# Is this a valid way to check if a point is in front of a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

So first things first, I know you can plug in the point's coordinates into the equation of the plane, and check the sign of the result.

But I had an interview recently where I had a brain fart and I came up with an alternate solution, and was told it was wrong. It seemed intuitive to me but I wanted to know for certain:

1. Calculate a vector going from our point to an arbitrary position on the plane
2. Get the surface normal from our equation of a plane
3. Calculate the dot product between the two
4. If the dot product is less than 0, then the point is behind the plane, else it is in front

Is this incorrect, and if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which side of a plane is "in front of" it? The direction of increasing $x$ value? Increasing $y$ value? What if the plane is perpendicular to the $x$ direction? Towards the origin (this is the case where your approach works, if you fix the sign of the constant)? What if the plane is through the origin? You might have an answer to that question, but the interviewer might have had a different answer. I suspect it might have been a trick question, checking whether you clarify things you need to know or just assume they have the same answer as you.

Assuming you defined "in front of" the same way, and assuming your way of calculating the surface normal ensured it had the correct sign, your approach would work. But you would need to tell  the interviewer how you are getting the surface normal, to ensure it's the right one - you can't just say "the surface normal" and assume it's the right one. At the very least, you'd have to specify how you were calculating the surface normal - I don't think there's a standard convention for which normal to use (again, positive $x$? Positive $z$?)

More fundamentally, if this was a job interview, then being right isn't enough. If you worked at that company, and your manager asked to to test if a point is in front of a plane, and you replied with something that worked but they didn't believe it, they wouldn't be willing to implement your solution. How do they know there isn't some edge case where your solution fails? How do they explain what they've done to their own manager? Being able to explain your work is at least as important as getting the right answer in the business world.

Comment: To clarify, "in front of" in this case was established as being on the same side of the plane with the outbound surface normal. Additionally we should support any orientation of the plane and point of interest.

Comment: Your last point is true as well, I didn't justify my explanation well enough and just gave up when he didn't understand it.